# Linking more than one subMenuItem to the same tabItem and updating tabBox?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am working on a shinydashboard app and am trying (see reprex below) to point three different menuSubItems to the same tab, while also updating a tabBox on that tab that corresponds to the menuSubItem a user clicks on.

Rationale: I am implementing this so a user can navigate to sub-pages more easily depending on where their cursor is, i.e. over the sidebar or on the page.

Current state: As you can see in the code below, I am 85% of the way there thanks [to this helpful response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61154768/extract-name-of-active-tab-of-shiny-dashboard) using javascript (tabs_js).  The script I've written assigns the actual text in the `<a>` of the clicked tab to input$activeTab, and then updates the selected tabBox panel using an observeEvent conditional on the changing input$activeTab state.

Issues:  Since the "tabName" in all three menuSubItems is the same, clicking on any of them only shows the first as clicked in the sidebar (i.e. aria-selected = true only for element 1).  Is there any way to preserve this many-to-one submenu approach and show the relevant submenu as clicked?  And in general, is there a more elegant way to solve this problem?

Reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

tabs_js <- '
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a[data-toggle=tab").click(function(){
     var el = $(this).text().trim();
     Shiny.setInputValue("activeTab", el);
   });
})
'


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(id = "side_id",
                menuItem("Boxes", tabName = "boxes", selected = T),
                menuItem("Foxes", tabName = "foxes",
                         menuSubItem("Loxes", tabName = "loxes"),
                         menuSubItem("Roxes", tabName = "loxes"),
                         menuSubItem("Noxes", tabName = "loxes")
                ),
                verbatimTextOutput("selected_tab_text")
    )),
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    tags$head(
      tags$script(HTML(tabs_js))
    ),
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "boxes",
              tabBox(
                tabPanel("One")
              )),
      tabItem(tabName = "foxes"),
      tabItem(tabName = "loxes",
              tabBox(id = "lox_box",
                     tabPanel("A"),
                     tabPanel("B"),
                     tabPanel("C")
              )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(session, input, output) {
  
  observeEvent(input$activeTab,{
    if(input$activeTab == "Loxes"){
      updateTabItems(session, "lox_box", "A")
    } else if(input$activeTab == "Roxes"){
      updateTabItems(session, "lox_box", "B")
    } else if(input$activeTab == "Noxes"){
      updateTabItems(session, "lox_box", "C")
    }
  })
  
  
  output$selected_tab_text <- renderPrint({
    input$activeTab
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

EDIT:

I have discovered that the javascript functionality falls apart if any element of the sidebar is rendered via renderMenu (see new reprex below).  How is it then possible to access the current ul / li elements in the sidebar menu via JS?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

tabs_js <- '
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a[data-toggle=tab]").click(function(){
     var el = $(this).text().trim();
     Shiny.setInputValue("activeTab", el);
   });
})
'


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(id = "side_id",
                menuItem("Boxes", tabName = "boxes", selected = T),
                menuItemOutput("fox_menu"),
                verbatimTextOutput("selected_tab_text")
    )),
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    tags$head(
      tags$script(HTML(tabs_js))
    ),
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "boxes",
              tabBox(
                tabPanel("One", actionButton("tog", "Toggle"))
              )),
      tabItem(tabName = "foxes"),
      tabItem(tabName = "loxes",
              tabBox(id = "lox_box",
                     tabPanel("A"),
                     tabPanel("B"),
                     tabPanel("C")
              )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(session, input, output) {
  
  observeEvent(input$activeTab,{
    if(input$activeTab == "Loxes"){
      updateTabItems(session, "lox_box", "A")
    } else if(input$activeTab == "Roxes"){
      updateTabItems(session, "lox_box", "B")
    } else if(input$activeTab == "Noxes"){
      updateTabItems(session, "lox_box", "C")
    }
  })
  
  output$fox_menu <- renderMenu({
    menuItem("Foxes", tabName = "foxes",
             menuSubItem("Loxes", tabName = "loxes"),
             menuSubItem("Roxes", tabName = "loxes"),
             menuSubItem("Noxes", tabName = "loxes")
    )
  })
  
  output$selected_tab_text <- renderPrint({
    input$activeTab
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I answered my own question (2/2 now on SO!).  The answer was mainly JS based.  First, I changed the JS code to look like this.  It finds the active `<a>`, gets the text, removes the 'active' class from any current `<li>`, then makes the one the user clicked active.

```
jscode <- "
shinyjs.setVal = function(){
     $('#sidebarCollapsed').find('a[data-toggle=tab]').click(function(){
       var el = $(this).text().trim();
       Shiny.setInputValue('activeTab', el);
   
       var sideb = this;
       
       $('#sidebarCollapsed').find('li.active').removeClass('active');
       $(sideb).closest('li').addClass('active');
   });
};
"
```

Then I added it to the dashboardBody using extendShinyjs.

```
 dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    extendShinyjs(text = jscode, functions = c("setVal"))
```

Finally I created an observeEvent to trigger the JS function

```
  observeEvent(input$side_id,{
    js$setVal()
  })
```

Note that the sidebar id was "side_id".  This approach triggers the tabBox tab that equals the menuSubItem by looking up its name and also makes the relevant `<li>` active.  For some reason this breaks the tab rendering in a complex modularized app I've written, but that's for another day.

Full product:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

jscode <- "
shinyjs.setVal = function(){
     $('#sidebarCollapsed').find('a[data-toggle=tab]').click(function(){
       var el = $(this).text().trim();
       Shiny.setInputValue('activeTab', el);
  
       var sideb = this;
       
       $('#sidebarCollapsed').find('li.active').removeClass('active');
       $(sideb).closest('li').addClass('active');
   });
};
"


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(id = "side_id",
                menuItem("Boxes", tabName = "boxes", selected = T),
                menuItemOutput("fox_menu")
    )),
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    extendShinyjs(text = jscode, functions = c("setVal")),
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "boxes",
              tabBox(
                tabPanel("One", actionButton("tog", "Toggle"))
              )),
      tabItem(tabName = "foxes"),
      tabItem(tabName = "loxes",
              tabBox(id = "lox_box",
                     tabPanel("A"),
                     tabPanel("B"),
                     tabPanel("C")
              )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(session, input, output) {
  
  observeEvent(input$activeTab,{
    if(input$activeTab == "Loxes"){
      updateTabItems(session, "lox_box", "A")
    } else if(input$activeTab == "Roxes"){
      updateTabItems(session, "lox_box", "B")
    } else if(input$activeTab == "Noxes"){
      updateTabItems(session, "lox_box", "C")
    }
  })
  
  output$fox_menu <- renderMenu({
    menuItem("Foxes", tabName = "foxes",
             menuSubItem("Loxes", tabName = "loxes"),
             menuSubItem("Roxes", tabName = "loxes"),
             menuSubItem("Noxes", tabName = "loxes")
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$side_id,{
    js$setVal()
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```