# How to use capture and use only the variables from the active tab in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shinyapps

How to use the same variable name across different tabs to store different values?

Here is a workable code.

```
require(shiny)
require(shinydashboard)


# Define the UI
ui <- dashboardPage(
  # Title of the app
  dashboardHeader(title = "Shiny App"),
  # Navigation panel
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Home", tabName = "home", icon = icon("home")),
      menuItem("Tab 1", tabName = "tab1", icon = icon("circle-nodes")),
      menuItem("Tab 2", tabName = "tab2", icon = icon("circle-nodes"))
    )
  ),
  
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "tab1", 
              fluidRow( 
                column(selectInput(inputId = "disease",
                                   label = "Disease",
                                   choices = c(
                                     "Breast Cancer" = "BreastCancer",
                                     "Kidney Cancer" = "KidneyCancer",
                                     "Skin Cancer" = "SkinCancer")
                ),
                textOutput({
                  "output_text_tab1"
                }),
                width = 6)
              ) # End of fluidRow
      ), # End of tab 1
      tabItem(tabName = "tab2", 
              fluidRow(
                column(selectInput(inputId = "disease",
                                   label = "Disease",
                                   choices = c(
                                     "Breast Cancer" = "BreastCancer",
                                     "Kidney Cancer" = "KidneyCancer",
                                     "Skin Cancer" = "SkinCancer")
                ),
                textOutput({
                  "output_text_tab2"
                }),
                width = 6)
              ) # End of fluidRow
      ) # End of tab 2
    ) # end of tabItems
  ) # end of dashboardBody
) # end of dashboardPage



# Define server logic to plot  ----
server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$output_text_tab1 <- renderText({ paste0("Tab1 Disease: ", input$disease) })
  output$output_text_tab2 <- renderText({ paste0("Tab2 Disease: ", input$disease) })
  
}

# Call the app
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Here, the variable `disease` is used in both `tab1` and `tab2`. When I use the drop-down from `tab1` and print the value, it prints correctly. However, when I move to `tab2` and try to reselect the `disease`, it still prints the value selected previously in `tab1`.

One way to solve this would be to define separate names. But while dealing with long codes, this might be not feasible.

How to use capture and use variables from the active tab? Is it possible to use a separate server function for each tab such that only the variable defined within that tab will be used?

Comment: In the shiny world the `inputId` values have to be unique. They are used as IDs in the html elements. You can get the name of the current tab and that might make this easier to get the correct input name: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61154768/extract-name-of-active-tab-of-shiny-dashboard

Comment: Would it be possible to use Shiny modules for this by defining separate modules for each tabItem?